# When there's 1 job take me to the job listing not the company page

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Feature request, when there is one job the company is offering and I click on it the system should take me to this said job.  Taking me to the company page makes no sense as then I have to click the job listing from there.

The feature request is it should simply take me to that single job listing (provided there is one listed for that company).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is by design, *company page search* takes user to company page and *job search* takes user to job listing page.

Also, you could use *job search* to get all jobs at a particular company:

[image]

Comment: But if you're on the "search companies" tab this doesn't make any sense.  Go to the search companies tab and type "thyssenkrupp" it displays 1 job as my picture above shows.  Why should that one job click take me to the company page????  I'm interested to see that one single job not the company page.  Sorry -1 this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JonH Clicking the "1 job" button thing on the companies search tab auto scrolls you to the open job section of the company details. I think this makes perfect sense and is consistent with how it'd be for all companies...

Comment: @Joe - But I am clicking that 1 job, so it takes me to the company page and scrolls me down to the available jobs which is that one job...which I have to yet again click?  I'm sorry this doesn't make absolutely any sense.  If it were MORE than 1 job I would say yes it should take me to the company page and scroll me to the correct anchor...but this is NOT the case.  I don't agree and I will fight this vigorously!

Comment: @JonH This is by design, "search companies" tab taking users to job listings doesn't make sense because it is "search companies" and not "search jobs". Also, what Joe said.

Comment: @JonH I expect the UI to behave consistently, irrespective of the data behind it.

Comment: @KirtiThorat - So If I see a label that says <b>yahoo.com</b> and I click on it it shouldn't take me to yahoo's website?  Come on get over the "its status by design"...status by design means you originally wrote it thinking that is the way it should work.  Status by design doesn't mean you cannot change something stop with the concrete stuff and think outside the box for a minute.  Your answer is not UX friendly.

Comment: @Joe - So go ahead and continue clicking jobs twice until you find your job...I on the other hand want to work faster.

Comment: @JonH I'd use the "search jobs" tab if I were looking for a job, it'd probably be quicker ;)

Comment: @Joe - Maybe the link shouldn't say 1 job, maybe it should say "Click here to go to the company page so that again you can click another link to get to the job"

Comment: @Joe it shouldn't matter which tab you are on.  If something says "1 job" I expect clicking on it would take me to said job, not take me to a company page and anchor me...If I see a delete button it best delete what I want delete, not taking me to a page showing the details of the record and having me delete again.  This is plain ol' asinine and I'm tired of all the weirdness on the jobs site.  I've posted enough about jobs and some of the status by design just doesn't make sense.  Eliminate the tags jobs and feature request if you don't want to support the community providing input.

Comment: Aside from that the job listing page already links me back to the company page itself!  Stop with the malarkey already and fix this!